# Building JSON Path for a datalist

Tags: json, grafana, jsonata

I am trying to import some data from an API and graph it using Grafana, the issue is the json is structured with no keys.  They are simply dates and counts shown below:

```
[["10","2024-01-07"],["241","2024-01-08"],["288","2024-01-09"],["692","2024-01-10"],["286","2024-01-11"],["263","2024-01-12"],["11","2024-01-13"],["83","2024-01-15"],["220","2024-01-16"],["228","2024-01-17"],["170","2024-01-18"],["250","2024-01-19"],["11","2024-01-20"],["10","2024-01-21"],["8","2024-01-22"]]
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but I'm trying to create a field for the count and a field for the dates.  Any help would be nice. thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map operator](https://www.stedi.com/docs/mappings/jsonata/jsonata-operators/path#map) to iterate over each tuple as follows:

```
$.({
  "date": $[1],
  "count": $[0]
})
```

Try it on the JSONata playground: https://stedi.link/k15AHBV

Comment: That seems to work somewhat, is there a way I can Cast the count as an Integer instead of a string?

Comment: NVM , i got it by doing "count": $number($[0])